# F# verbose syntax and class definition problem

Tags: class, syntax, f#, verbose

I'm baffled by the fsharp-error given for following code in `test.fsx`:

```
let Kasper = "Kasper" in printfn "%A" Kasper
type student (name: string) =
  class
    member this.name = name
  end
let aStudent = student Kasper in printfn "%A" aStudent.name
```

which gives the following error,

```
% fsharpc test.fsx && mono test.exe
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 10.2.3 for F# 4.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

/Users/sporring/Desktop/test.fsx(2,1): error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'type' in implementation file
%
```

I have found the following solutions:

- move the `printfn "%A" Kasper.name;` to a new line
- move the whole construction `let Kasper = "Kasper" in printfn "%A" Kasper` below the type definition
- convert it all to lightweight syntax

So it seems, that I don't understand the scope of the `let-in` expression. Would someone please help me understand why the original code fails to compile? Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure how the compiler parses this, but `let-in` is not a top level structure item. It's not just a different form of `let`, and therefore does not mix with `type`. When you do `let ... in ...`, and it works as expected, it's most likely because it's wrapped in an implicit top-level `let`, ie. `let _ = let ... in ...`. So for some reason it seems to think that `let-in` on a single line should be followed by an expression, which `type` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verbose syntax of F# is odd and there is a good reason why it's discouraged :-).

The `let .. in ..` construct is an expression, but the top-level in a module (which is what you need when you also want to use `type`) behaves differently. At the module level, you can use `let` to define top-level values, but this is not `let .. in ..` expression but rather a declaration `let <pat> = <expr>`. You can also use the `do` keyword at the top-level if you want to run some code when the module is initialized, which is written as `do <expr>`. So, to make your example work, you can use:

```
#light "off"
let Kasper = "Kasper" do printfn "%A" Kasper
type student (name: string) =
  class
    member this.name = name
  end
do let aStudent = student Kasper in printfn "%A" aStudent.name
```

To show more options, I write the first `let` as a top-level declaration, but the `aStudent` value is defined as a local binding in a `do` block.

Comment: Thanks glennsl and Tomas, is there any good reason, why the top level of a module is treated differently than lower levels?

Comment: @Jon - I think the main reason is that the top-level needs to allow declarations (exports, types) and so it cannot be treated as "everything is an expression". At the lower level, things are simpler, because you do not need other kinds of declarations.

Comment: I checked (https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), and indeed `expr` has the `let function-defn in expr` syntax, while the `module-function-or-value-defn` in the module definitions uses the `let function-defn` syntax. It seems to be an unnecessary distinction, but in any case, now I realise the source. Thanks, Jon